# Tool for OS X that allows multiple monitors to act as one (Video Wall Driver)

Tags: osx, display, video-conferencing

We have an array of six 55" TV screens arranged in a video wall driven by a single Mac. It looks gorgeous, and is great for multitasking in meetings. (e.g. showing a document to the group at large while having a Skype call with someone remote)

However, we haven't found any software we can use to them make them all act like a single monitor. This is important for full-screening presentations and videos. Is there a tool out there (Commercial or FOSS) that will do this for us?

(We are aware that LibreOffice has a screen-spanning presentation mode that works pretty well, but there are other applications we need to use fullscreen.)

Comment: The only thing I found is for iOS :( http://www.theverge.com/2012/11/1/3584632/pinch-smartphone-tablet-synchronized-display-link-interface-app  But why can't you just arrange the monitors in the system preferences as a grid and resize the app over all screens?

Comment: Interesting article, though not what we need :(. In answer to your question, that doesn't work as well as you might think. You have to be very careful because if the windows want to snap to one screen. Dragging a window over twelve feet of screen is kind of a bummer when one wrong move causes the window to suddenly contract to 1/6th the size you want it to be. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would work in your case, but I've seen several things online that say that disabling the "Displays have different spaces" option in System Preferences could help. Try going to System Preferences > Mission Control and unchecking the checkbox for "Displays have different spaces". Log out and log back in, and see if that helps. 
I found this at: http://www.imore.com/how-span-window-between-two-displays-mavericks
I have no idea how full-screen applications would work with this, however. They would probably stay confined to a single monitor, which may not work based on the description of the problem that you provided.

I found something for videos spanning multiple monitors here: https://superuser.com/questions/461269/how-to-watch-a-video-in-full-screen-on-multiple-monitors. I'm not sure if a video would work for your purposes, though.

Note: I probably would have put some of this into a comment instead of an answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: We were already aware of both of these, and they are both helpful though they don't really solve our problem. However,  I'm accepting your answer because you put some time in on a question I asked the better part of a year ago and I appreciate your effort. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I don't really look at when questions were posted... so... :)